# What are the differences between these words: varying, varied, various, and a variety of?

Tags: meaning

May I ask what is the difference between the use of 'varying', 'varied', 'various' and 'a variety of'? Many thanks!

Comment: Jane, you'll be very welcome to ask that after you've posted what research lead you to think there was a problem.

Broadly, what did did your paper or on-line dictionaries fail to explain?

Comment: For the record, you can no more have differences "among" words than the eye of a daisy can ever be "among" its petals. These always have to be "between", just like choosing between several candidates, never "among" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Varying - having the ability to differ
- Varied - being of different kinds, having the ability to include difference
- Various - a collection of things that differ from one another
- A variety of - a selection of different examples of the type mentioned, or, a particular kind of one of them.

Varying: (having the ability to differ)

- I have varying reasons for leaving - they keep changing - one day, I love Tom - the next, I hate him. Or I feel it’s not practical - then it seems worth it. My feelings vary (change).
- Varying schedules exist in the curriculum (things happen at different non-standard times, or, schedules themselves differ (ie - ‘have the ability to vary’)

Varied: (being of different kinds,having the ability to include difference)

- My reasons for leaving are many and varied. They encompass several differing major areas of my life - work, relationship, and spiritual.
- I varied my diet by adding more raspberries and plums
- I varied my contract to include more time off

Various: (a collection of things that differ from one another)

- There are various reasons why I want to leave, emotional, physical financial - and even more different ones that I haven’t even thought about yet.
- There are various kinds of applE in the basket
  (differing apple varieties eg Tom Smiths etc)
- There are various kinds of appleS in the basket (differing types such as Tom Smiths, also other conditions like, fresh, mouldy, tart, sweet)
- There are various fruits in the basket (apples, oranges, bananas, cherries)

A variety of: (a selection of different examples of the type mentioned, or, a particular kind of one of them.)

- There are a variety of reasons why I want to leave (which I’ve pre-analysed and can tell you - they are a, b, c, and d)
- There are a variety of apples in the basket - French Golden Delicious, Tom Smith’s and Amber. I selected them for you to try.
- There is one variety of apple I prefer above all others - French Golden Delicious.

Links to more explanation and examples

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/variety

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/various

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/varying

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/varied

Answer (score 1):

'**varying**' - participle -> *To be in the process of changing **at the time referred to***

"I am/was/will be varying the conditions of your employment"

and adjective "The varying quality of the light made photography difficult."

'**varied**' - past participle = *of an item that has changed or has been changed in the past* "I have varied the conditions of your employment"

'**Varied**' - Adjective: *of an item that is represented in several forms as a result of change or being changed* "The varied quality of the apples meant that they could not be sold."

'**various**' - adjective: of items in a random collection

'**variety** - noun = a random set of types of an item.

Comment: ["There are a number of routes to the summit, with varying levels of difficulty."](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/vary?q=varying) (OLD) Clearly, the meaning of *varying* is not restricted to your usage.

Comment: !+1 for mentioning the verb and its forms.

Answer (score 0):

Varying is connected to changing or changing over time.
Varied is different or differing, options

So a varying diet is a diet that I change from time to time, maybe every few months I eat low carbs for a month.
A varied diet is a diet that has different kinds of foods groups.

Comment: Hello, Toby. This could be the start of a good answer. But good answers on ELU contain linked and attributed supporting references, either from recognised authorities (eg dictionaries) or direct from some type of corpus. They also address the whole question (which is admittedly over-broad in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Varying his routine, he took a walk in the park.

Various books were strewn on the floor.

A variety of books were stacked on the table.

You should eat a more varied diet.  No one can survive on only diet Coke and pizza.

Please consult this [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/varied).

Comment: But are they interchangeable and is there any difference in their meaning and usage?

Comment: @Jane Take any of the example sentences and try replacing the word it uses with one of the other words. You'll find that doing so will result in something ungrammatical.

Comment: In my understanding we can say 'varied books were stacked on the table'; 'varying books were stacked on the table';  'various books were stacked on the table'; and  'a variety of books were stacked on the table'? I don't know but just sometime when I use them in my writings, editors would correct it but I don't know how to differentiate four of them...

Answer (score -1):

"What are the differences ***between*** these words: varying, varied, various, and a variety of?"

"Between" is for two items--the comparative degree. AMONG is for three or more items to compare or contrast.

Comment: Answers should only be used to directly answer the question. If you want to challenge the premise of a question or the details, you should use the comments under the question itself. This option will become available when you gain the necessary reputation by asking and/or answering questions.